# Running Python with VS Code - The basics

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Unfortunately I am but another noob who is frustrated by my lack of understanding what are likely very basic concepts... So here it goes!
I simply want to understand the concept behind me running the windows python version command in the .py file, and it not working, versus the same command being run directly in the command prompt, and the command working. To illustrate:

[image]
I write the command in the editor and run the script. The result is an error.

[image]
I run the same command directly into the terminal within VS Code. It works.
What concept am I missing here? I can print 'Hello World', but I cannot run the version command?

Comment: Because you are trying to run a shell command with the Python interpreter. That won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing OS commands with Python.

To run anything with Python, you must follow and use its programming guidelines and APIs https://docs.python.org/3/

To print Python version write this in your script:

```
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
```

To print python version on windows cmd run:

```
  python --version
```

or you are using:

```
  py -3 version
```

Comment: Ah! I think I get it now. The command I was using wasn't even python! I got it from VS code's tutorial site. They are giving me OS commands, not python.. So I can still run python script so long as they are valid commands?

Comment: Yes OS commands can be used to install packages etc. But inside Python it must adhere to its API.

Comment: Interesting, with a `conda` environment activated on VSCode terminal or Anaconda command line `python --version` shows Python version of that environment while `py -3 --version` shows the base default Python version...

Answer (score 0):

`VS Code` terminal is a shell CLI (command line interface) providing interface to  OS (in this case `PS` in VS Code terminal is a Windows `PowerShell`). Inside Python .py file you can not run shell commands as-is from command-line. Still shell commands can be run inside python scripts, for example, inside .py file

```
import os
# older way, os.system deprecated
print("%d" % os.system("python --version"))

# it's replacement subprocess
import subprocess
py_v1 = subprocess.run(["py", "-3", "--version"])
print("%d" % py_v1.returncode)

py_v2 = subprocess.run(["python", "--version"])
print("%d" % py_v2.returncode)

py_v3 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "--version"])
print(py_v3.communicate())
```

Output ([more on `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html))

```
Python 3.7.4
0
Python 3.7.4
0
Python 3.7.4
0
Python 3.7.4
(None, None)
```